# Detecting new loop when interval starts at 0 again

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with a VBA code.

I have a database in which names are listed. Each name has several intervals! Starting at the maximum top with value '0' and ending with a maximum base at a certain depth (2000-4000).

Each interval is classified with a number (1 to 6).
I want to make a continuous series with a certain incremental step. This means that the intervals are replaced by a continuous series with small incremental steps. And next to the continuous series, the classification is noted.

The results are put in a second worksheet ('Samples' sheet).
I managed to get the results I want for 1 name. Now I want to get results for more Names, but I don't know how to let the code know that it needs to start a new loop at a new name and do the same all over again (new maximum top of '0').

I would like to have the results of every new name in a new workbook if possible.

This is my code which I have constructed till this point:

[Code]

```
Sub IntervalToSample()

Dim Cancelled As Boolean, OldStatusbar As Boolean
Dim NOI As Integer, TI As Integer, TS As Integer, DOF As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, Samples As Integer, SII As Integer
Dim Counter As Long, Bounter As Long
Dim Top As Double, Base As Double, Inc As Double, TopI As Double, BaseI As Double
Dim WellN As String, Well_Name As String, Well_Top As String, Well_Base As String
Dim Incremental_Step As String, Total_Intervals As String, Total_Samples As String
Dim MainWkbk As Workbook, Well1 As Workbook
Dim Start As Worksheet, Data As Worksheet, Sheet1 As Worksheet

OldStatusbar = Application.DisplayStatusBar

Set MainWkbk = ActiveWorkbook

DOF = 5
Counter = 0
Bounter = 0
SII = 0
WellN = Sheets("Data").Cells(DOF + 1, 1)
Top = Sheets("Data").Cells(DOF + 1, 2)
Inc = Sheets("Start").Cells(1, 6)
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
TI = ActiveCell.Row - DOF
Base = Sheets("Data").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3)
TS = Int((Base - Top) / Inc) + 2

Incremental_Step = Sheets("Start").Cells(1, 5)
Well_Name = Sheets("Start").Cells(2, 5)
Well_Top = Sheets("Start").Cells(3, 5)
Well_Base = Sheets("Start").Cells(4, 5)
Total_Intervals = Sheets("Start").Cells(5, 5)
Total_Samples = Sheets("Start").Cells(6, 5)

Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "H:\.......\.......\VBA\Code Set-up\VBA-DATABASE\Well1.xls"
Set Well1 = ActiveWorkbook

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 5) = Well_Name
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 5) = Well_Top
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 5) = Well_Base
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 5) = Total_Intervals
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 5) = Incremental_Step
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 5) = Total_Samples

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 6) = WellN
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 6) = Top
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 6) = Base
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 6) = TI
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 6) = Inc
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 6) = TS

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.StatusBar = True

 If Not Cancelled Then
  MainWkbk.Activate
  For i = 1 To TI
    MainWkbk.Activate
    TopI = Sheets("Data").Cells(i + DOF, 2)
    BaseI = Sheets("Data").Cells(i + DOF, 3)
    Samples = CInt((BaseI - TopI) / Inc)
    Well1.Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 12) = Samples
    Application.StatusBar = i
  Next i

  For i = 1 To TS
   Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 8) = Top + (i - 1) * Inc
  Next i

  For i = 1 To TI
    SII = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 12)
    If i = TI Then SII = SII + 1
    For j = 1 To SII
      Counter = Counter + 1
      Well1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 9) = MainWkbk.Sheets("Data").Cells(i + DOF, 13)
      Bounter = Bounter + 1
      Well1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Bounter, 10) = MainWkbk.Sheets("Data").Cells(i + DOF, 34)
     Next j
  Next i

End If                                    

Well1.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
MainWkbk.Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = Range("A1").Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = OldStatusbar
```

End Sub

[Sheet 'Data'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdLgv.png)

['Sheet1' in new workbook 'Well1'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSYC8.png)

Comment: What do you mean "each name has several intervals"?

Comment: So you want to loop down through your data and restart your procedure each time you encounter a new name?

Comment: As a general comment, your variables are not all declared as you expect them to be. `Dim Cancelled, OldStatusbar As Boolean` declares `Cancelled` as a Variant and `OldStatusbar` As a Boolean. If you want them both to be a Boolean, you need to change it to `Dim Cancelled As Boolean, OldStatusbar As Boolean`.

Comment: @Kyle: I have a list in Column 'A' with 2 names (see picture sheet 'Data'). Both names have several intervals (Column B=Top and Column C=Base). I want my code to detect that it needs to start with a new loop when the name changes in Column A, which is the same as finding a value of '0' in Column B (maximum top=surface level). My real database is set up the same way, but there are more than 200 'names'. But I want to keep it simple at first, so that I really understand what is happening.

Comment: @TheEngineer
Yes that is exactly what I want to do. My real database has over 200 names. And I want the loop to restart everytime a new name is found in Column A. I managed to do this for 1 name, but when I add a second name the loop just continues without starting a new loop. I want the results to be splitted, preferably in a new excel file.

Comment: @TheEngineer
Do you mean that I need to do this for every 'Dim' row? So every time declaring the variable?

Comment: Yes, every `Dim` row needs each variable declared separately. Otherwise they will all be inherently `Variant`. I'll work up an answer a little later

Comment: @The Engineer
Thank you very much I changed the Dim's. I will wait for your answer!

Comment: @The Engineer: I managed to incorporate adding a new workbook in my code. The results of the first 'name' are put in this new workbook.

Comment: @The Engineer: Now I'm Looking into getting a Dim variable as file name for my newly created workbook.

Comment: Great! I suggest updating your code in your question and I'll take a look at it. It will be until tomorrow before I can get back to this. One other suggestion is to assign your worksheets to variables declared as `Worksheet` and your workbooks to variables declared as `Workbook`. That will help when working with multiple workbooks and it will make it easier if you ever need to change a worksheet name in the future.

Comment: @TheEngineer: I updated my code in the Question. I declared the workbooks and sheets. This meant that I needed to change the name of sheet "samples" in sheet "start".

Comment: @TheEngineer: I'm not sure yet if I want to make a new workbook for every new name. However, I do know that at least I want to create a new workbook for the results. I managed to do this as you can see in the new code. The most important thing now is to let the code loop again when a new name is reached. This will also mean that the results need to move at least a few columns with every new name. But I want to keep the same layout for every new name.
I guess that I need to move the part in which I define the results into the loop section. But, I think it is better if you take a look at this.

Comment: The layout of the results I want to get is show in the picture of  'Sheet1 in new workbook Well1'. In the mean time I will ofcourse try to start the new loop myself. But it would be great if you could take a look at it :)

Comment: I just added an answer. I didn't add the loop code to your code because you'll need to combine your three loops first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a cleaned up version of your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub IntervalToSample()

Dim Cancelled As Boolean, OldStatusbar As Boolean
Dim NOI As Integer, TI As Integer, TS As Integer, DOF As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, Samples As Integer, SII As Integer
Dim Counter As Long, Bounter As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim Top As Double, Base As Double, Inc As Double, TopI As Double, BaseI As Double
Dim WellN As String, Well_Name As String, Well_Top As String, Well_Base As String
Dim Incremental_Step As String, Total_Intervals As String, Total_Samples As String
Dim wbMain As Workbook, wbWell1 As Workbook
Dim wsStart As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet, wsSheet1 As Worksheet

OldStatusbar = Application.DisplayStatusBar

Set wbMain = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsStart = wb.Sheets("Start")
Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Data")

DOF = 5
Counter = 0
Bounter = 0
SII = 0
WellN = wsData.Cells(DOF + 1, 1)
Top = wsData.Cells(DOF + 1, 2)
Inc = wsStart.Cells(1, 6)
LastRow = wsData.Columns(1).End(xlDown).Row
TI = LastRow - DOF
Base = wsData.Cells(LastRow, 3)
TS = Int((Base - Top) / Inc) + 2

With wsStart
    Incremental_Step = .Cells(1, 5)
    Well_Name = .Cells(2, 5)
    Well_Top = .Cells(3, 5)
    Well_Base = .Cells(4, 5)
    Total_Intervals = .Cells(5, 5)
    Total_Samples = .Cells(6, 5)
End With

Set wbWell1 = Workbooks.Add
wbWell1.SaveAs "H:\.......\.......\VBA\Code Set-up\VBA-DATABASE\Well1.xls"

Set wsSheet1 = wbWell1.Sheets("Sheet1")
With wsSheet1
    .Cells(1, 5) = Well_Name
    .Cells(2, 5) = Well_Top
    .Cells(3, 5) = Well_Base
    .Cells(4, 5) = Total_Intervals
    .Cells(5, 5) = Incremental_Step
    .Cells(6, 5) = Total_Samples

    .Cells(1, 6) = WellN
    .Cells(2, 6) = Top
    .Cells(3, 6) = Base
    .Cells(4, 6) = TI
    .Cells(5, 6) = Inc
    .Cells(6, 6) = TS
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.StatusBar = True

If Not Cancelled Then
    For i = 1 To TI
        TopI = wsData.Cells(i + DOF, 2)
        BaseI = wsData.Cells(i + DOF, 3)
        Samples = CInt((BaseI - TopI) / Inc)
        wsSheet1.Cells(i, 12) = Samples
        Application.StatusBar = i
    Next i

    For i = 1 To TS
        wsSheet1.Cells(i, 8) = Top + (i - 1) * Inc
    Next i

    For i = 1 To TI
        SII = wsSheet1.Cells(i, 12)
        If i = TI Then SII = SII + 1
        For j = 1 To SII
            Counter = Counter + 1
            wsSheet1.Cells(Counter, 9) = wsData.Cells(i + DOF, 13)
            Bounter = Bounter + 1
            wsSheet1.Cells(Bounter, 10) = wsData.Cells(i + DOF, 34)
        Next j
    Next i
End If

wbWell1.Close True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = OldStatusbar

End Sub
```

Notice that I added `Option Explicit` at the top. This requires you to declare all of your variables before the code will run. You did a good job of this, but it is always good to include.

Also, I'm not sure what the purpose of `If Not Cancelled Then` is. You don't use the variable `Cancelled` anywhere else in your code, so it will always be the same.

You have three different For loops in your code. I suggest combining them into one if you can so you don't need to loop down through thousands of lines of data multiple times. You can then add the following to account for the change in name:

```
Dim curName As String
Dim NameCount As Long

'Add this just before your For loop
curName = wsData.Cells(DOF + 1, 1).Value
NameCount = 0

'Add this just inside your For loop
If wsData.Cells(i + DOF, 1) <> curName Then
    curName = wsData.Cells(i + DOF, 1).Value
    NameCount = NameCount + 1
End If
```

You can then use `curName` and `NameCount` to change where the data is being stored for the new name.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! I cleaned up my code as you suggested and it still works. I'm now looking into combining my 'For Loops'.

Comment: Great! If you have any questions, let me know and I can update my answer. If this answer satisfies your request, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Can you help me further? I tried several things, but combining the loops is challenging. Also the curName and NameCount don't work properly. I updated my loop code below.

Comment: It will be difficult for me help you combine your loops without knowing what each loop is trying to accomplish. Also, you should not add an answer that is incomplete. If you have updated code, just revise your question to include it. If you find the right answer yourself, you can add that and mark it as correct.